# Continuation passing style procedures

Tags: lambda, scheme, evaluation, sicp, continuation-passing

I have troubles understanding how procedures in continuation passing style "remember" values from previous function calls.

As an example I have the following procedure that will filter the even values from a list:

```
(define (get-pairs alist proc)
  (if (null? alist)
      (proc '())
      (get-pairs
       (cdr alist)
       (lambda (l)
         (let ((num (car alist)))
           (if (zero? (remainder num 2))
               (proc (cons num l))
               (proc l)))))))
```

Then I call it with:

```
(get-pairs '(1 2)
           (lambda (n) (display n)))
```

To get the expected result `(2)`.

`get-pairs` will recursively call itself until its parameter `alist` is empty. Then the last function call would be: `(get-pairs '() proc)`. `proc` would be the procedure:

```
(lambda (l)
         (let ((num (car alist)))
           (if (zero? (remainder num 2))
               (proc (cons num l))
               (proc l))))
```

In this lambda body, `alist` and `proc` are the parameters of the function call that came prior: `(get-pairs '(2) proc)`. My question is, how does each lambda procedure "remembers" the parameters of past function calls if `proc` is evaluated only at the very end?

Or is it that at each call to `get-pairs`, the body of the lambda passed as argument to the next call is "analyzed", with the corresponding values of `alist` and `proc` already substituted into its body?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR:* *closures* created by tail-call-optimized functions must capture a *copy* of (relevant parts of) their definitional environment. Or, just ignore the TCO part, and treat it as you would a regular recursive function, where any lambda function created during the recursive function's execution is a closure, captures the values of variables that it refers to.

---

This can be understood in the framework of the *environment* model of Scheme evaluation.

Each call to `(lambda (...) ...)` creates a new lambda function object, implicitly paired up with its definitional environment, together known as *closure*.

Each invocation of `get-pairs` creates its own fresh new call frame, and any lambdas created from *that* will hold onto the hidden pointer into *(a copy of)* that frame.

This can be easier to see with the following variants, which perform exactly the same function as the one in the question:

```lisp
(define (get-pairs1 alist proc)
  (if (null? alist)
      (proc '())
      (get-pairs1
       (cdr alist)
       (let ((alist alist))   ; creates fresh new environment frame
         (lambda (l)
           (let ((num (car alist)))
             (if (zero? (remainder num 2))
                 (proc (cons num l))
                 (proc l))))))))

(define (get-pairs2 alist proc)
  (if (null? alist)
      (proc '())
      (get-pairs2
       (cdr alist)
       (let* ((alist  alist)
              (num  (car alist))
              (newproc 
               (if (zero? (remainder num 2))
                   (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l)))
                   (lambda (l) (proc l)))))
         newproc))))
```

`proc` is *not* "evaluated at the very end", the *procedure* which is the variable `proc`'s value is *called* at the very end, but the variable `proc`'s value is found out at each invocation. And at each invocation that value is different, i.e. *new* lambda function object is created afresh on each separate invocation of `get-pairs`. The value of the variable `proc` at each invocation of `get-pairs` is different.

So, for the example call `(get-pairs2 '(1 2 3 4) display)`, the final `proc`'s call is the same as

```
((lambda (l4)             ;                  |
    ((lambda (l3)          ;             |   |
        ((lambda (l2)       ;        |   |   |
            ((lambda (l1)    ;   |   |   |   |
                (display      ;  1   2   3   4
                 l1))         ;  |   |   |   |
             (cons 2 l2)))   ;       |   |   |
         l3))               ;            |   |
     (cons 4 l4)))         ;                 |
 '())

;; i.e.
;;  l1 = cons 2 l2
;;              l2 = l3
;;                   l3 = cons 4 l4
;;                               l4 = '()
```

Which can also be written, in pseudocode, as

```
(((((display ∘ identity) ∘ {cons 2}) ∘ identity) ∘ {cons 4}) '())
;   └───────1──────────┘
;  └───────────────2───────────────┘
; └─────────────────────────3──────────────────┘
;└───────────────────────────────────4─────────────────────┘

;; 1: created on 1st invocation of `get-pairs2`
;; 2: created on 2nd invocation of `get-pairs2`
;; 3: created on 3rd invocation of `get-pairs2`
;; 4: created on the final 4th invocation of `get-pairs2`, 
;;    and then called with `'()` as the argument
```

where `{cons n}` signifies a partially applied `cons`, i.e. `(lambda (l) (cons n l))`, and `identity` is `(lambda (l) l)`.

Oh, and `∘` stands for the function composition, `(f ∘ g) = (lambda (x) (f (g x)))`.

See also some other of my answers that might be relevant, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20pseudocode%20collector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891%20pseudocode%20cps).

---

Working through the invocation `(get-pairs2 '(1 2 3 4))` step-by-step, with `let`-based re-writes emulating the function calls, we get (simplifying a bit)

```
(get-pairs2 '(1 2 3 4) display)
=
(let ((alist '(1 2 3 4))                       ; '(1 2 3 4)
      (proc  display))                         
  (let* ((num (car alist))                       ; 1       
         (newproc (lambda (l) (proc l))))            
    (let ((alist (cdr alist))                    ; '(2 3 4)  
          (proc newproc))                          
      (let* ((num (car alist))                     ; 2   
             (newproc (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l))))) 
        (let ((alist (cdr alist))                  ; '(3 4)
              (proc newproc))         
          (let* ((num (car alist))                   ; 3  
                 (newproc (lambda (l) (proc l))))  
            (let ((alist (cdr alist))                ; '(4)
                  (proc newproc))
              (let* ((num (car alist))                 ; 4
                     (newproc (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l)))))
                (let ((alist (cdr alist))              ; '()
                      (proc newproc))
                  (proc '()))))))))))
```

Loading it up in DrRacket's code editing window and hovering with your mouse over the various identifiers is a fun game that lets you see what each identifier is referring to. Running this code with Ctrl-R also produces the same results as the the original function call.

Another "fun" exercise is to go over the above nested `let` expression and manually rename each identifier by adding a unique index to it (changing `proc` to `proc1`, `proc2` etc.) so each name becomes unique.

Okay, I'll do it for you, especially that DrRacket has a nice "rename identifier" feature which makes it much easier and less error-prone. But do try doing it on your own too.

```
(let ((alist '(1 2 3 4))                         ; '(1 2 3 4)
      (proc  display))
  (let* ((num (car alist))                         ; 1
         (newproc (lambda (l) (proc l))))
    (let ((alist2 (cdr alist))                     ; '(2 3 4)
          (proc2 newproc))
      (let* ((num2 (car alist2))                     ; 2
             (newproc2 (lambda (l) (proc2 (cons num2 l)))))
        (let ((alist3 (cdr alist2))                  ; '(3 4)
              (proc3 newproc2))
          (let* ((num3 (car alist3))                   ; 3
                 (newproc3 (lambda (l) (proc3 l))))
            (let ((alist4 (cdr alist3))                ; '(4)
                  (proc4 newproc3))
              (let* ((num4 (car alist4))                 ; 4
                     (newproc4 (lambda (l) (proc4 (cons num4 l)))))
                (let ((alist5 (cdr alist4))              ; '()
                      (proc5 newproc4))
                  (proc5 '()))))))))))
```

So you see, it's not the same `proc`. There are five of them, each  potentially different, each residing in a different, nested environment frame.

---

You might ask, why *nested* environments? After all the `get-pairs2` is tail-recursive, so it must not do that, can re-use its call frame for the next invocation.

That's true, but still it's an implementational detail related to the code's operational efficiency, which doesn't change its meaning (semantics). *Semantically* it is much easier to see what the code means, with the nested `let` re-writes.

Nevertheless that is a valid point and potential source of your confusion. I once was confused exactly by this point as well.

And that is why I wrote "*(the copy of)* the environment frame" there at the start of this post. Even if the tail-recursive call can -- maybe even must, under Scheme's TCO guarantee -- re-use its own call frame for the next invocation, the freshly created closure must hold on to *its own copy*, to not introduce the erroneous conflation of semantically different identifiers.

---

Indeed, that environment flattening and frame reuse can be described by the following timeful computation:

```
;; re-use the tail-recursive call frame {alist proc}
(let ((alist '(1 2 3 4))
      (proc  display)
      (num #f))
  (set! num  (car alist))                        ; 1
  (set! proc (let ((num num) (proc proc))        ; closure!
               (lambda (l) (proc l))))
  (set! alist (cdr alist))                       ; (2 3 4)
  (set! num  (car alist))                        ;  2
  (set! proc (let ((num num) (proc proc))        ; closure!
               (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l)))))
  (set! alist (cdr alist))                       ;   (3 4)
  (set! num  (car alist))                        ;    3
  (set! proc (let ((num num) (proc proc))        ; closure!
               (lambda (l) (proc l))))
  (set! alist (cdr alist))                       ;     (4)
  (set! num (car alist))                         ;      4
  (set! proc (let ((num num) (proc proc))        ; closure!
               (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l)))))
  (set! alist (cdr alist))                       ;      ()
  (proc '()))
```

Or as the definition which it might actually get compiled as,

```
(let ((alist '(1 2 3 4))
      (proc  display)
      (num #f))
  (let loop ()
    (set! num  (car alist))
    (set! proc (let ((num num) (proc proc))
                 (if (zero? (remainder num 2))
                     (lambda (l) (proc (cons num l)))
                     (lambda (l) (proc l)))))
    (set! alist (cdr alist)) 
    (if (null? alist)
       (proc '())
       (loop))))
```

So how many `proc`s are there now? :)

<sub>(still five, for otherwise it wouldn't be working... i.e. there's one *binding* but five *values* were created during the loop's run, each encasing the previous one inside it (or, actually, holding a reference to it); and when the last `proc` value -- which is a function -- finally runs, it invokes the one "inside" it, and that one invokes the one "inside" *it*, and so on going back to the very first `proc`, the `display` which which we've started.)</sub>

Comment: A great answer! I will actually need to study it to fully understand it but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: thanks, you're very welcome! :) It was fun writing it. (btw there are two more variants hidden inside the answer, coming back to normal-looking Scheme with named loop etc.. I thought they could be confusing, so commented them out. check out [the one-before-last](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63732116/14) version of the answer to see them)